# java.lang.NullPointerException Error in my chat application

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

I'm pretty new to programming, so I follow a guide on Youtube that helps to build my chat application. Until now, sending messages via firebase from one user to another works fine, but when I'm trying to enter the conversation that contains new messages, the app crashes. However, once I try to enter the chat after the app crashed, it works fine.

This is the code for the ChatFragment:

```
package com.example.messengerapp.Fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.RecoverySystem
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.messengerapp.AdapterClasses.UserAdapter
import com.example.messengerapp.ModelClasses.Chat
import com.example.messengerapp.ModelClasses.Chatlist
import com.example.messengerapp.ModelClasses.Users
import com.example.messengerapp.R
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener

private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

class ChatFragment : Fragment() {

    private var userAdapter: UserAdapter? = null
    private var mUsers: List<Users>? = null
    private var usersChatList: List<Chatlist>? = null

    lateinit var recycler_view_chat_list: RecyclerView
    private var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser? = null

    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false)
        recycler_view_chat_list = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_chat_list)
        recycler_view_chat_list.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recycler_view_chat_list.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)

        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

        usersChatList = ArrayList()

        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("ChatList").child(firebaseUser!!.uid)
        ref!!.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot)
            {
                (usersChatList as ArrayList).clear()

                for (dataSnapshot in p0.children)
                {
                    val chatlist = dataSnapshot.getValue(Chatlist::class.java)
                    (usersChatList as ArrayList).add(chatlist!!)
                }
                        //TODO:: Check why function below crashes
                        retrieveChatLists()
            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError)
            {

            }

        })
        return view
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            ChatFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }

    private fun retrieveChatLists()
    {
        mUsers = ArrayList()
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")
        ref!!.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot)
            {
                (mUsers as ArrayList<Users>).clear()
                for (dataSnapshot in p0.children)
                {
                    val user= dataSnapshot.getValue(Users::class.java)
                    for (eachChatList in usersChatList!!)
                    {
                       if (user!!.getUID().equals(eachChatList.getId()))
                       {
                           (mUsers as ArrayList).add(user!!)
                       }
                    }
                }
                userAdapter = UserAdapter(context!!, (mUsers as ArrayList<Users>), true)
                recycler_view_chat_list.adapter = userAdapter
            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError)
            {

            }
        })
    }

}
```

This is how I built the UserAdapter:

```
package com.example.messengerapp.AdapterClasses

import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.Context
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.content.Intent
import android.media.Image
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.messengerapp.MessageChatActivity
import com.example.messengerapp.ModelClasses.Users
import com.example.messengerapp.R
import com.example.messengerapp.WelcomeActivity
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.user_search_item_layout.view.*

class UserAdapter(mContext: Context, mUsers: List<Users>, isChatCheck: Boolean) : RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder?>(){
    private val mContext: Context
    private val mUsers: List<Users>
    private val isChatCheck: Boolean

    init {
        this.mUsers = mUsers
        this.mContext = mContext
        this. isChatCheck = isChatCheck
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): UserAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.user_search_item_layout, viewGroup, false)
        return UserAdapter.ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UserAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val user: Users = mUsers[position]
        holder.userNameTxt.text = user!!.getUserName()
        Picasso.get().load(user.getProfile()).into(holder.profileImageView)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
            val options = arrayOf<CharSequence>("Send Message", "Visit Profile")
            val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
            builder.setTitle("What would you like to do?")
            builder.setItems(options, DialogInterface.OnClickListener{dialog, which ->
                if (which == 0)
                {
                    val intent = Intent(mContext, MessageChatActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("visit_id", user.getUID())
                    mContext.startActivity(intent)
                }

                if (which == 1)
                {

                }

            })
            builder.show()
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mUsers.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        var userNameTxt: TextView
        var profileImageView: CircleImageView
        var onlineImageView: CircleImageView
        var offlineImageView: CircleImageView
        var lastMessageTxt: TextView

        init {
            userNameTxt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username)
            profileImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image)
            onlineImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_online)
            offlineImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_offline)
            lastMessageTxt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_last)
        }
    }

}
```

When I'm trying to run the app, as was mentioned, I get the java.lang.NullPointerException exception. When I click on that in the run tab, it brings me to this line in the ChatFragment:

```
userAdapter = UserAdapter(context!!, (mUsers as ArrayList<Users>), true)
```

This is the Logcat:

```
2020-11-03 15:05:46.345 18520-18520/com.example.messengerapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.messengerapp, PID: 18520
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.messengerapp.Fragments.ChatFragment$retrieveChatLists$1.onDataChange(ChatFragment.kt:112)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

I'm not quite sure what the problem is. Hope that I gave the right information.
Please help!

Comment: post the logs...

Comment: Edited the Logcat!

Comment: ChatFragment.kt:112 is what causing problems

Comment: Likely `context` is `null`, because it had been declared nowhere. Just set a break-point at line `112` and hover with the mouse over the variables, in order to inspect them.

Comment: I think I fixed it! I changed the line to  userAdapter = context?.let { UserAdapter(it, (mUsers as ArrayList<Users>), true) } Do you think it's okay?